# A problem that may be dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I encounter a problem. After some search, it seems a bit like dynamic programming, like knapsack problems or number division problems, but a little different from the typical ones. I'm not sure how to solve this problem. (If it is a typical problem please tell me its name)

> Given *n* items of various weights, and many identical knapsacks of
> capacity *W* to carry them all. Find the best combination of items
> that minimize the number of knapsacks to use.
>
> For example: Given 4 items of weights 1，3，8，10; knapsack capacity 11;
>
> the best combination is {1, 10} and {3, 8} that uses only 2 knapsacks.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: SO is about specific technical questions/problems, if you have a specific language you want to solve this problem i suggest you ask it in its official forum

Comment: Look for "bin packing"